# What does "get back on my feet" mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching a very short YouTube video. In [the 53 second of the video](https://youtu.be/45mgOuoVN4E?t=53), the man says

> And if I ever get back on my feet again sir, I'll bring it back.

What does "get back on my feet" mean? From the context I guess it probably means "if I have enough money in the future", is it correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/back+on+feet), **back on one's feet**:

> 3. No longer in a precarious financial situation.
>    *Now that I've paid off my credit card debt, I'm finally back on my feet.*
>    (Farlex)

> 3. *Fig*. recovered from anything, especially financial problems. (*Typically: **be ~; get ~.**)
>    *I can't afford to buy a car until I get a job and get back on my feet. I'll get back on my feet as soon as I start working again.*
>    (McGraw-Hill)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Btw I'm not lazy, I tried to look it up in the dictionary. But I'm looking up "get back" & "get back on" and I don't know the actual usage here is "back on one's feet". Thanks again for your help!